# How to find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty }(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{(2018n+1)^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> How to find $$\lim_{n\to \infty }(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{(2018n+1)^4}$$

---

My attempt:

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{(2018n+1)^4}=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^{\left(4\cdot 2018n+4\right)}=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^{\left(4\cdot 2018n\right)}+\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^4\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^{n}\right)^{4*2018}+\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^4\right)$$

so we get :

- $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^4=1$

let:

$b_n=\frac{-5}{n^3}$

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{-5}{n^3}=0$

- $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^n\right)^{4\cdot 2018}=\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(\left(1+\frac{b_n}{n}\right)^n\right)^{4\cdot \:2018}=\left(e^0\right)^{4\cdot 2018}=1$

so the answer is :

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{(2018n+1)^4}=1+1=2$$

Is this answer correct if not how can I find the limit ?

thanks.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: How do you justify the first step $(2018n+1)^4=4\cdot 2018 n +4n$?

Comment: this is exam question and i don't remember if it was $((1-5/n^4)^{(2018n+1)})^4$ or $(1-5/n^4)^(2018n+1)^4$ ,  but this is how i solve it so i guess if it $(1-5/n^4)^(2018n+1)^4$  so my answer is wrong

Comment: @J.Doe note that this step $(2018n+1)^4=4\cdot 2018 n +4n$ is absolutely wrong. Can you follow the solution given? Please do not hesitate to ask for any clarification about it.

Comment: @gimusi  I got it , thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to consider

$$(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{(2018n+1)^4}=e^{(2018n+1)^4 \log{(1-\frac{5}{n^4}) }}\to e^{-5\cdot2018^4}$$

indeed by standard limits

$${(2018n+1)^4 \log{(1-\frac{5}{n^4}) }}=(2018n+1)^4(\frac{5}{n^4})
\frac{\log {(1-\frac{5}{n^4})}}{\frac{5}{n^4}}\to -5\cdot2018^4$$

Or as an alternative

$$(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{(2018n+1)^4}=\left[(1-\frac{5}{n^4})^{\frac{n^4}5}\right]^{\frac5{n^4}(2018n+1)^4}\to e^{-5\cdot2018^4}$$

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that the limit is practically $0$ as the exponent $5\cdot 2018^4$ is almost infinity :) +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes of course, since $5\cdot2018^4$ has order $10^{14}$  the limit $e^{-5\cdot2018^4}$ is "very close" to 0 but not at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $m=2018n+1$ then $\lim _{m\to \infty }\big(1-5\frac{2018^4}{(m-1)^4}\big)^{m^4}$

=$\lim _{m\to \infty }\big(1-5\frac{2018^4}{(m-1)^4}\big)^{{m^4}\frac{(m-1)^4}{(m-1)^4}}$

=$\lim _{m\to \infty }\big(1-5\frac{2018^4}{(m-1)^4}\big)^{{(m-1)^4}{\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{m})^4}}}$

Known that $\lim _{m\to \infty }\big(1-\frac{x}{m}\big)^{m}=e^{-x}$

The limit is equal to $e^{-5*2018^4}$

Answer (score 1):

The result seems to me weird. You wrote $\displaystyle \left(2018n+1\right)^4=4\left(2018n+1\right)$ which is false. And you when an expression is at power $n$, you cannot say the argument tends to $0$ hence it tends to $0^n$.

I would rather write
$$
\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^{\left(2018n+1\right)^4}=e^{\left(2018n+1\right)^4\ln\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)}
$$
Then
$$
\ln\left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{=}-\frac{5}{n^4}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)
$$
and
$$ \left(2018n+1\right)^4=2018^4n^4+o\left(n^4\right)=16583822760976n^4+o\left(n^4\right)$$
Finally

> $$
> \left(1-\frac{5}{n^4}\right)^{\left(2018n+1\right)^4}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}e^{-82919113804880}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also write

$$(1-5/n^4)^{(2018n +1)^4} = [(1-5/n^4)^{n^4}]^{(2018n +1)^4/n^4}.$$

Inside the brackets we have the limit $e^{-5},$ while the outer exponent $\to 2018^4.$ Thus the desired limit is $e^{-5\cdot 2018^4}.$ (We have used the result: If $a_n \to a\in (0,\infty)$ and $b_n\to b\in \mathbb R,$ then $a_n^{b_n} \to a^b.$ This is worthwhile proving for yourself, as it comes up often.)